# Samsung Chromebook series 3 sudo password

Tags: linux, sudo, chromebook

I cannot for the life of me find the sudo password for my chromebook. I have it in dev mode on Chrome OS 41. I want to install Arch Linux ARM onto an SD card but the instructions here http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/samsung/samsung-chromebook

say type `sudo su` and you won't be prompted for a password...I am asked and I have no idea whst it is

Comment: Have you tried _your own_ login password?

Comment: Yes, along with `root` `chromeos` `chronos`